# Complicated trigger insert rows depending of value in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, subquery

I have an Oracle database with a table "Trains".

Each train got a JourneyID and a departureDate as foreign keys (references Journey).

A Journey is a regular trip that a train do on a regular basis (each day, only in the week, only week-ends, special period for vacations, etc...). A journey got a date of departure and a date of arrival. It also contains the dates of the period (begin and end) and a periodicity rule (a varchar, like "everyday" "every week-end", "each day of the week").

I would like to create a trigger that insert a new train, associated to the right journey, for each day in the period, depending of what the period's rule says.

I have a few problems :

How can i write such a trigger ? The trigger will... trigger once per statement, so there is no risk of triggering because of the trigger, right ?

How can i test the periode attributes where my journey foreign key match the period primary key ?

How can i do a "for each day between" with a set of date ? How to handle gaps in the days (like "not week-end" or "only week-end" conditions).

Is it only possible to do such a manipulation with SQL ?? (i assume that yes, but with a lot of subqueries inside the trigger).

Here is my try for each day in the interval :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Auto_Creation_Trains
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Trajets
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF type = "Regulier - Taille Normale"
  THEN
    CREATE SEQUENCE temp MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAX VALUE 366
    WHILE (temp != fin_periode - debut_periode)
    LOOP
      temp.nextval
      INSERT INTO (trainID,Sits1,Available1,Sits1,Available2,journeyID, depart) TrainInfo(IDTrain.next, 150,150,647,647,:NEW.journeyID);
    END LOOP;
    DROP SEQUENCE temp
  END IF;
END;
```

Does it seems legit ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea should work, the idea that insert many records to another table when this table get a new record. But the code you put here is arguable.

1. I feel it is not necessory to use a sequence in here, just a for loop should do the trick.
2. it should be:

   INSERT INTO traininfo (trainID,Sits1,Available1,Sits1,Available2,journeyID, depart) values (IDTrain.next, 150,150,647,647,:NEW.journeyID)
3. unless this is just a draft and your real insert statement is different, I don't understand why you need to insert 365 same records into traininfo table.

Comment: You're right, the sequence is not usefull, i didn't know i could do more simple things. It's not the same record, it's suppose to have the last attribute that change each time. That point one of my mistakes here, i forgot to insert the last attribute. This last attribute is the date that is supposed to increment at each iterations. If a do a DATE+1, the result will be the next day ?

Comment: Yes, it will be like this: For i in 1..365 LOOP next_date = trunc(sysdate)+i;....